# MySql Get scrambled results

Tags: php, mysql

Current scenario :

I have a MySQL database (products_db) with product links ('links') .
Now the products / links are from 11 different websites (advertisers).

Is there some sort of MySQL query I can make to get the results in groups of 11 links, one link for each website ?

The point is to get a list of results with all the links, one link for each 11 website .

I know I can use the following to get the first 11 rows each from a different website, but I need ALL the results arranged like that .

```
SELECT id, name, advertiser, link
FROM table
GROUP BY advertiser
```

If not, I guess I have to go back to sort the list in PHP ..

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` instead of `order by`:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table GROUP BY id
```

Comment: sorry, the query is made with GROUP BY .. my bad .. q. edited.

Comment: try doing  group by `link`.

Comment: you want to group them by what?

Comment: i want to group them by advertiser (one link for each website, there are 11 different websites, 11 advertisers) but I only get 11 results from that query, not all the links